# Where to Find Original Manuscripts Of Mishne Torah

Tags: history, rambam, mishneh-torah

I have a couple versions of books from Mishne Torah: some of them are from Mishne Torah HaRav Kook edition, and the other book I have is Mishne Torah Hashalem Edition and it says there that it is fully meduyak based on the Kitvei Yad. Does that mean it's the original edition Rambam wrote? I want to see the difference between the two versions (Mishneh Torah Hashalem and HaRav Kook edition) so where or how can I find an original copy of Mishne Torah online and which is the most original online as well? As I heard there was a lot of censorship in the book.

[image: The Two different versions of Rambams Books]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, we have no original edition of Mishne Torah that Rambam wrote. What we do have is a manuscript of only the first two books (Mada & Ahavah), with a autographed statement from Rambam, attesting that it was checked (proofread?) against his personal manuscript (called "ספר המוגה"). For the rest of Mishne Torah, usually Yemenite manuscripts are relied upon for accuracy. (That's what [Mechon Mamre](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/0.htm) and the [Yosef Qafih edition](https://net-sah.org/library/1075) generally do.)

Comment: Maybe worth taking a look at Wikipedia's [Mishneh Torah#Printed editions and textual accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishneh_Torah#Printed_editions_and_textual_accuracy).

Comment: Indeed there was censorship. My rosh yeshiva zt"l had a copy of the first printed edition which was hand-censored by church officials. On this topic, you might want to check out Yaakov S. Spiegel's עמודים בתולדות הספר העברי - הגהות ומגיהים, where the last chapter is dedicated to textual variations in printed editions of Mishneh Torah over the years. Availabile online at Otzar Hachochmah and Kotar.

Comment: I believe I once found a manuscript on the site of the National Library of Israel which was signed by a scribe who stated he accurately copied the text from a copy autographed by the Rambam. I'll see if I can find it again.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the original was written in Judeo-Arabic

Comment: Do we know how many People copied the Manuscript in the first place and who where the people who had the first Copies? Also what's the story on how did they first printed Mishne Torah?

Comment: @יהושעק AFIK, Rambam's commentary to Mishnah was originally written in Judeo-Arabic, and that original manuscript is today found in Israel's National Library., but the Mishneh Torah was originally written in Hebrew.

Comment: The manuscript (of Mada & Ahavah) I mentioned is available online as [Huntington 80](https://digital.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/objects/60f5a5d4-8e17-457a-8280-0e0fdd43a1b6/surfaces/61ec32f6-cd8d-4ea0-bca7-1ee40ac7f930/) on the Bodleian Library website.

Comment: @IsraelReader you may be right, indeed that would make sense (given the purpose the Mishnah Torah was written for)

Comment: When it says "Kitvei yad", it almost always means earlier manuscripts that are not by the author, unless otherwise noted. The advantage is that they are often free from later errors and censors, but they could have their own mistakes.